# React: Reorder list causes unwanted transitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, transition

I have a list of stuff implemented in React, that can be reordered by a couple of buttons to move up and down.

The issue I'm having is that because I have a Toggle component that is implemented with CSS and have transitions between the states, when I change the order between two rows that have different toggle state, I see the transition that I only want to see then clicking the toggle, not while reordering.

Here is a gif of the issue for better explanation.

[image: issue demo]

I understand that this is how React works, that just renders and change the differences, that's why it's just changing the attribute and that's how I see the transition to happen.

My question is, Is there a way to avoid this?

**EDIT:** The solution is right. Although I was using the key attribute, the value of it was the index of the array. That made React confused an unable to determine the right element.

Comment: what did you use instead of the array index for the key values?

Comment: In this case I used the ID of the record on database, but you could use a random generated one if you don't have an ID already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the `key` property set for every element in your list.

This will enable react to reuse the existing DOM elements instead of re-rendering them, which should solve your issue. It should also improve the performance in the process.

---

> [...] React supports a `key` attribute. When children have keys, React uses
>   the key to match children in the original tree with children in the
>   subsequent tree.

[Source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children)

Comment: To add more information I was using the index as the key, so it was confusing React on identifying the right elements.